# Was bedeutet "verblasst" innerhalb von Bedeutungsangaben im Wörterbuch?

Tags: dictionary

Zur Seite bestimmten Bedeutungen im Duden, bin ich dem Wort "verblasst" begegnet in Bezug auf den Gebrauch des Wortes, z.B. in [vornehmen (4)](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/vornehmen#Bedeutung-4).

Nach dem ich die Bedeutung[en] des Verbs "verblassen" gelesen habe, die etwa "blass, schwächer werden" ist, ist mir immer noch nicht klar, was es **sprachlich** bedeutet.

Was bedeutet es denn, wenn der Gebrauch eines Wortes "verblasst" bzw. "meist verblasst" ist? Ist es ähnlich wie "selten"?

Comment: `verblasst` als Gebrauchscharakterisierung erscheint mir auch ungewöhnlich: ich könnte mir *vorstellen*, dass es "seltener werdend" bedeuten solle (was aber m. E. auf das angegebene Beispiel gerade nicht zutrifft). In Bezug auf Sprache kann ich mir *verblassen* nur in folgender Wendung vorstellen: "Die ursprüngliche Bedeutung von ... ist verblasst, heutzutage wird das Wort nur noch im Sinne von ... verwendet", d. h. die ursprüngliche Bedeutung ist mit der Zeit verloren gegangen.

Comment: @Stef Find' ich etwas komisch, dass die gebrauchscharakterisierende Bedeutung von "verbasst"/"verblassen", die sie selber im Duden ab und zu nützen, da im Wörterbuch fehlt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wenn die Bedeutung eines Wortes verblaßt, bedeutet das, daß Sprecher die ursprüngliche oder wörtliche Bedeutung des Wortes nicht mehr wahrnehmen.

Das geschieht im Deutschen regelmäßig bei sogenannten *Funktionsverbgefügen*. Anstelle des einfachen

> untersuchen

benutzt man

> eine Untersuchung vornehmen

Die Bedeutung des Ganzen liegt im Nomen *Untersuchung*; das Verb *vornehmen* trägt dazu nahezu nichts mehr bei. Seine Bedeutung ist in dieser Verbindung verblaßt. (Man hat nicht das Gefühl, daß eine Untersuchung in die Hand genommen und irgendwohin getragen wird.)

Wenn die ursprüngliche Bedeutung eines Wortes verblaßt, kann dies dazu führen, daß Sprecher es anders benutzen und die Bedeutung sich ändert. Ein Beispiel wäre das Wort *merkwürdig*: ursprünglich hieß es *erinnernswert, denkwürdig*. Das [DWB](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=merkwuerdig) hat den Beleg:

> alles was geschieht, das merkwürdige wie das unbedeutende, reiszt der zeitstrudel mit sich in die vergessenheit hinab.

Aber heute bezeichnet *merkwürdig* das Seltsame, Verwunderliche, Auffallende. Wieder das DWB:

> das ist ein merkwürdiger kerl *(von einem der durch sein thun oder wesen auffällt)*

Also bedeutet *verblaßt* hier nicht, daß das Wort selten benutzt wird.

Answer (score 2):

Der Duden selbst gibt zwei Bedeutungen des Verbs "verblassen" (und damit auch des Partizips "verblassend") an:

1. blass werden
2. schwächer werden, schwinden

Zu 2. gibt der Duden das Beispiel "die Erinnerung daran verblasst allmählich".

Zum Verb "vornehmen" gibt der Duden mehrere Definitionen, inbesondere

4. durchführen

Gebrauch: meist verblasst

Beispiele:

```
    eine Änderung, Untersuchung vornehmen (etwas ändern, untersuchen)
    an/bei jemandem eine Operation, einen Eingriff vornehmen (jemanden operieren)
```

In diesem Kontext kann "verblasst" nur in der Bedeutung "schwächer werden, schwinden" gemeint sein. Der Duden behauptet also, dass "vornehmen" in diesem Sinne eine aus dem Sprachgebrauch verschwindende Redewendung sei. Das ist jedoch eindeutig **falsch**. Im Gegenteil handelt es sich um eine bis heute sehr häufige Art der Verwendung.