# Verwendung von Ausdrücken mit "ergreifen"

Tags: word-usage, phrase, dictionary, archaism

Das Wort **ergreifen** wird unter anderem in Ausdrücken wie "Initiative ergreifen", "einen Beruf ergreifen" usw. verwendet. Benutzt man immer noch solche Ausdrücke? [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ergreifen) und [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/ergreifen) behaupten, dass sie schon verblasst/abgeblasst sind — was genau bedeutet das?

Comment: [Diese Ausdrücke werden weiter verwendet](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Beruf+ergreifen%2CInitiative+ergreifen%2CMacht+ergreifen&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=de-2019&smoothing=0). [Verblasst bedeutet](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/59029/6495) hier meines Erachtens, dass das Verb außerhalb einiger fester Ausdrücke nicht mehr in dieser Bedeutung verwendet wird.

Answer (score 3):

Ich bin da mit Duden und DWDS nicht ganz einig: Zumindestens innerhalb feststehender Ausdrücke (von denen es so viele gibt, dass man schon fast nicht mehr davon reden kann) wird *ergreifen* im übertragenen, nicht physischen Sinn, sehr wohl noch relativ häufig verwendet:

- einen Beruf ergreifen
- die Macht ergreifen ("Machtergreifung")
- die Initiative ergreifen
- Partei ergreifen (im Sinne von "sich auf eine bestimmte Seite stellen")
- das Wort ergreifen
- eine Chance ergreifen
- von etwas Besitz ergreifen

und das auch in "Allerweltskommunikation", in der Zeitung und in den Nachrichten.

*Ergreifen* im Sinne einer realen physischen Handlung dagegen ("er ergriff das Glas, ihre Hand,...) finde ich meiner Erfahrung nach nur noch in der Literatur (also in Romanen) und in Polizeiakten ("er ergriff das Messer und stach sofort zu") - sowas *sagt* niemand mehr wirklich.

Comment: *Den Täter ergreifen* im Sinne von *festnehmen* ist vielleicht noch am dichtesten an der physischen Handlung.

Comment: Vielen Dank für Ihre Erklärung!